# Implementing a form validation plugin with AngularJS with Django REST at the server side

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am now implementing a client side using Angular for a Django REST Framework backend.

In order to get the Alpha of the project up and running in the briefest time, we decided to use the server side validation directly.

Django rest returns a JSON string with one to one correspondence between the fields and the errors.

This feature of Django could allow me to implement such a feature in jQuery in several minutes.

The question is how do I do it with angular?

Code example:

form:

```
<label for="uname">Login:</label>
                    <div class="inputUnit" name="email">
                        <input tpye="email" class="text" name="email" ng-model="formData.email">
                    </div>
<label for="password">password:</label>
                    <div class="inputUnit">
                        <input type="password" class="text" name="password" ng-model="formData.password">
                    </div>
```

JSON response from the server in case both of the fields are empty:

```
{"password": ["This field is required."], "email": ["This field is required."]}
```

JSON response from the server in case the password is missing and email doesn't match regex:

```
{"password": ["This field is required."], "email": ["Enter a valid e-mail address."]}
```

What is the best practice to implement a generic component to display those error to the user?

The desired HTML after displaying the errors:

```
<label for="uname">Login:</label>
                    <div class="inputUnit" name="email">
                        <input tpye="email" class="text" name="email" ng-model="formData.email">
<label for="error">Email error here</lable>
                    </div>
<label for="password">password:</label>
                    <div class="inputUnit">
                        <input type="password" class="text" name="password" ng-model="formData.password">
<label for="error">Password error here</lable>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The reason I want to implement something like this: server side validation is always stronger and better.
Also some rules on the backend might change from time to time, and this way they'll ber updated on the front automatically

Comment: Seeing your controller would be nice too, or wherever you are posting the data to your server.

Comment: It is a simple controller, that uses a service to submit the form data to the API endpoint, and the API returns the json error string, if there's indeed an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you could find my attempt to handle server side validation errors with the directive https://github.com/9ci/angle-grinder/blob/c0211c885c561f8ec820b38d506135f4fb8b6dfb/app/scripts/modules/forms.coffee#L321 I hope it would be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code Lucas, this is the best answer so var.